# Elmah.MVC returns 403 in Local Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah.mvc

I have installed Elmah.MVC into a project I'm working on and tried to browse to /elmah but am constantly greeted by this error:

> You are attempting to access ELMAH from a remote machine whereas itis
>   currently configured not to allow remote access. You can enableremote
>   access by adding the following sections to this web
>   site'sconfiguration file:

```
<configuration>
         <configSections>
             …
             <sectionGroup name="elmah">
                 <section name="security" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
             </sectionGroup>
             …
         </configSections>
         <elmah>
            <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
         </elmah>
         …
     </configuration>
```

The thing is, I'm running the application in Debug mode on my Local Machine and not remotely.

My Web Config looks as follows:

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  ......
  <appSettings>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  ......
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  </httpModules>
  ......
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  ......
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah>
</configuration>
```

I've used Elmah before in other projects without encountering this issue. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, MVC5 and .NET Framework 4.5.2

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your entire web.config?

Answer (score 0):

I *HAD* the same issue. I was definitively accessing locally, I tried "localhost" and "127.0.0.1". 
But I could make it work with another smaller MVC project, at least remotely.

Comparing both, I noticed differences in the **version** of elmah.corelibrary, and I believe now that the latest version, 1.2.2 causes the issue.

So, I replaced 2 dll and have now

- Elmah.dll **v1.2**  (v1.2.13605.2128) (instead of 1.2.2 or 1.2.14706.0?)
- Elmah.Mvc.dll v2.1.2

and updated package.config :

```
<package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Elmah.Mvc" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
```

In the Root web.config, I have the following lines related to elmah

in the configSections section :

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  </sectionGroup>
```

in the appSettings section :

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
```

in the system.web section :

```
<httpModules>
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  </httpModules>
```

in the system.webserver section :

```
<modules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

and under configuration

```
<elmah>
   <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
</elmah>
```

I struggled a lot to make it all work. This last attribute can of course be set to false (and it still works locally)
I hope it works for you!

Comment: note that nuget package explorer mentions both elmah v.1.2.2 and elmah.corelibrary v.1.2.2, I'm a bit confused.